# Push Error: remote: error: File target/file.war is 146.41 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB

Tags: git, github

I want to push a repo to Github but I get the following error:

```
remote: error: Trace: 34493ed538bd789e39e61fbc0...

remote: error: See https://gh.io/lfs for more information. 
Remote: error: File target/file1.war is 146.41 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB 
remote: error: File target/file2.war is 146.41 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB          
remote: error: File target/file.war is 146.41 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB 
remote: error: GH001: Large files detected. You may want to try Git Large File Storage - https://git-lfs.github.com.

To https://github.com/project-name/repo-name.git 
![remote rejected] main -> main (pre-receive hook declined) error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/project-name/repo-name.git'
```

The repo is from Bitbucket and I need to push it to Github, like a migration.

What am I doing is cloning the Bitbucket repo locally, adding the remote to repository created in Github and then pushing to this remote and I get the error.

```
git clone https://bitbucket.company_name.net/scm/project/repository.git
cd repository folder
git remote add github https://github.com/project-name/repo-name.git
git push github
```

There are no .war files in the locally cloned repo but there is a large .pack file in .git: .git\objects\pack together with a .idx and .rev file.

```
Thank you.
```

Solutions provided in "Git lfs - "this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB" " didn't help.

Comment: Maybe there is no `war` file at the tip of the branch (or branches) you are pushing _but_ there is a file with that name in the history of the branch..... you will need to rewrite history of the branch to remove it to be able to push it into github.

Comment: I have only 2 branches: master & develop. With  _git log master / git log develop_ I get only the commit # , Author, Date and commit message. How do I rewrite this part of history? I need the commits history but, for this to work, I can rewrite it/ delete it. Thanks